# Clone github repository in specific directory with terraform

Tags: github, terraform

This week I started to learn terraform to make server deployments and the thing is I need to clone a git repository in a specific folder, but after hours of research I didn't find how. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If your Git repository represents a [terraform module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html), you could [declare them](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#generic-git-repository) as

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git" 
}

module "storage" {
  source = "git::ssh://username@example.com/storage.git"
}
```

> Arbitrary Git repositories can be used by prefixing the address with the special `git::` prefix.
> After this prefix, any valid Git URL can be specified to select one of the protocols supported by Git.

---

If it is not a module, then you would need to  a [resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/github/r/repository.html)

```
resource "github_repository" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "My awesome codebase"

  private = true

  template {
    owner = "github"
    repository = "terraform-module-template"
  }
}
```

However, [k''](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6264829/k) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463462/clone-github-repository-in-specific-directory-with-terraform/60463729#comment129033586_60463729) this is for creating a repository. It is not for cloning it.
Same for [`github_repository`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository), which only allows you to create and manage repositories within your GitHub organization or personal account.

Comment: See also https://www.chrisanthropic.com/blog/2017/script-to-automate-importing-github-org-into-terraform/

Comment: But when terraform clones the repository, where is it? I mean, is the repository downloaded somewhere in my server?

Comment: @gramos As seen here (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11435#issuecomment-435680988), more in `.terraform/modules`, as resources used to build the machine, not as sources downloaded into the machine.

Comment: @VonC, I guess, second option with github provider, you can create repo. it's not for cloning.

Comment: @k'' Reading https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/tree/main/examples, that is possible indeed.

Comment: @VonC, there are no such example for "github_repository" but I found https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository This also only work to create repo, not for cloning.

Comment: @k'' Good point. I have included your comment in the answer to make that limitation more visible.

Answer (score 4):

For a clearer version of the [andybkay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16940309/andybkay)'s answer:

```
#pull the code from github
resource "null_resource" "git_clone" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "git clone git@github.com:useinsider/${var.git_repo}.git"
  }
}
```

And call this from CLI as follows:

```
terraform apply -var git_repo="<<your-repo-name>>"
```

Answer (score 3):

So this is a few years after the original ask, but this may be useful to anyone who may need it if they land here.

I've just had this issue, and the best solution is to use null_resource/local-exec.

```
resource "null_resource" "git_clone" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "../scripts/get_repo.sh"
    interpreter = ["bash"]
  }
}
```

../scripts/get_repo.sh should contain the following:

```sh
git clone <insert repo here> /put/your/destination/here
```

While not the cleanest, it does perform the job required.

(Checked with terraform 0.13.3)

Answer (score 1):

Terraform Github provider does not direct support cloning repository but there is another way to retrieve data of the repository and clone it. I would rather call it a semi-declarative approach.

Create *github_clone.tf* with following snippet -

```
provider "github" {
  token        = var.gh_token
  organization = "test-tf"
  base_url = var.gh_base_url
  version = "~>v2.9"
}

data "github_repository" "dummy" {
  full_name = "test-tf/dummy-tf"
}
```

to retrieve your secrets, create another file *vars.tf*

```
variable gh_token {
    default = "YOUR-GH-TOKEN"
}

variable gh_base_url {
    default = "YOUR-GH-BASE-URL"
}
```

Once saved initialize terraform with -

`terraform init`

- to download Github provider. Then run

`terraform show -json | jq -r '.values.root_module.resources[0].values.http_clone_url'`

It will return url to clone github repo.